# How do I make Unity quit opening Firefox under the Shiretoko icon?

Tags: unity, firefox

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and whenever I open Firefox, whether it is from searching on the dash or clicking a 'quick-launch' launcher, it always opens yet another icon for the running instance that is a blank page and says Shiretoko. It will pulse the Firefox icon for a while (I'm guessing until a timeout or something). It's as if Unity no longer recognizes the Firefox process as Firefox and misidentifies it as Shiretoko.

(I know Shiretoko was a testing version of Firefox a long time ago.)

How do I set Unity straight? I imagine that it has something to do with me once using Shiretoko, but I believe that was even on a different installation, just the same home folder. Is there some place Unity caches this information that I can clear (or remove specific parts of)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two folders where you can find all "starters" that Unity know and the Dash can find.
`/usr/share/applications` is the system wide folder and `/home/<yourusername>/.local/share/applications` is the one specific to your user.

You should have an entry for Firefox and for Shiretoko, delete the one you do not like.

This is an easy solution. If it does not help, you might want to dig deeper in how this works here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Good Luck!